# WordPress posts not paginating correctly

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I have a strange issue with my WordPress posts. I have a static front page and a post page called blog. I have a home.php template with my standard post loop.

I have set posts in the admin to only show 8 posts at most and I have the `<?php previous_posts_link(); ?><?php next_posts_link(); ?>` links. However when I enable the max post limit and pagination the ordering of my posts goes wrong.

Instead of displaying posts 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 then 9 10 in order, I get 3 1 10 9 8 7 6 5 on the first page then 9 10 4 1 on the second. It seems that posts 9 and 10 repeat themselves and post 2 just doesn't show at all.

I have tried `wp_reset_postdata()` and using `wp_query` to set the order and number but I still have the same issue. My current template is:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
    <!-- start content -->
       <?php if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
         <header class="page-header">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
         </header>
       <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        $i = 1;
        $count_posts = wp_count_posts();
        if ( $count_posts ) {
          $published_posts = count( $count_posts->publish );
        }
        while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();

          if ( $i > 1 && $i !== $published_posts ) {
            echo '<hr />';
          }
             get_template_part( 'partials/content', get_post_format() );
          $i++;
        endwhile;
        ?>
    <!-- end content -->
    <!-- start post nav -->
    <?php previous_posts_link(); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link(); ?>
    <!-- end post nav -->

</main>
<!-- if no content -->
<?php
  else :
    get_template_part( 'partials/content', 'none' );
  endif;
?>
```

When trying `wp_query` I did:

```
   $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;     
   $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => 8,
      'orderby' => 'menu_order',
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'paged' => '$paged',
    );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Which I ended with the `wp_reset_postdata()` after calling the pagination links.

I just think what could be causing the issue, so I was wondering if any of you guys could help?

Thanks for taking the time to read my post.

Comment: 'paged' => '$paged', Variable ($paged) in single quote, PHP treats as string. Convert it to double quotes.

Comment: Maybe, it helps(its similar to your question). [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105977/wordpress-pagination-not-working-always-showing-first-pages-content][1]

Comment: Hi @PankajVerma thanks for that I completely missed I had put it in single quotes.  Just tried putting doubles and removing quotes however, I still don't get the correct sorting. I'm now getting:

1, 4, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5 on the first page and 9, 10, 4, 1 on the second.

Comment: You should post this question on the Wordpress stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks, @Hemant I will have a look.

Comment: you are sorting according to menu_order, please check weather order is proper or not

Comment: As you need posts order by ID so replace 'orderby' => 'menu_order', with 'orderby' => 'ID'. also take care of order ASC.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the issue which I have never had before. With help from the comments above from Pankaj Verma and charan kumar I checked the `menu_order` param in the args. And hey presto when changing `menu_order` to another orderby param it fixed my issue.

After Google I have found many people having the same issue with menu_order. In my personally experience it has never happened for me before when I've used it. But it does seem to be a common issue.

So to resolve my issue I re-added wp_query and changed the options to:

```
$args  = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'orderby'        => 'ID',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'paged'          => $paged,
);
```

Hope this helps anyone else who is having similar issues and thank you to everyone who commented on my post, they were really helpful in solving this.